# How can I combine letters and Roman numerals in the enumerate environment

Tags: enumerate, letters, roman-numerals

```
Q.1
a)(i) What is physics? (1)
  (ii) Examples of branches   
        Of physics?
```

Comment: Please add a longer example and/or a description of the required numbering scheme(s).  Perhaps the `enumitem` package could help you.

Answer (score 1):

The basics can be easily achieved using [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)'s `label` key-value approach:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={Q.\arabic*}]
  \item \mbox{}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
      \item What is physics?
      
      \item Examples of branches of physics.
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```